# How do I make the TCPClient send stuff to the same IP, but different places?

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Ok, so, I have this code, that creates a TCPListener and a TCPClient, the code work, just not for me, my server is in my own home, in another machine, so I passed the server software to that and I tried to connect using my client, the client sends the request, the server picks it up, analyses it, and then throw it back, but, when it throws it back, the IP is the same so it's redirected to the server again, and the client never gets a response, This only happen in TCP tho, UDP do the job, but I need TCP to work

Server Code:

```
    Dim Listener As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8123)
    Dim Client As New TcpClient
    Dim Message As String = ""

    Dim games As New List(Of GameClass)
    Dim queue As New Dictionary(Of String, IPEndPoint)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim ListenerThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        ListenerThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Listening()
        Listener.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub Send(msg As String, ip As IPEndPoint)
        Try
            Client = New TcpClient(ip)
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Sending: " & msg & " to: " & ip.Address.ToString)
            'Declare the Client as an IP Address. 
            'Must be in the Correct form. eg. 000.0.0.0
            Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
            Writer.Write(msg)
            Writer.Flush()

            'Write the Message in the stream


        Catch ex As Exception
            Try
                Client = New TcpClient(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), ip.Port))
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Sending: " & msg & " to: " & ip.Address.ToString)
                'Declare the Client as an IP Address. 
                'Must be in the Correct form. eg. 000.0.0.0
                Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
                Writer.Write(msg)
                Writer.Flush()
            Catch ex1 As Exception

            End Try
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub Send(msg As String, index As Integer, ip As IPEndPoint)
        Try
            For Each item In games(index).IPAddresses
                If item.Value.Address.ToString = ip.Address.ToString Then
                Else
                    Client = New TcpClient(ip)
                    'Declare the Client as an IP Address. 
                    'Must be in the Correct form. eg. 000.0.0.0
                    Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
                    Writer.Write(msg)
                    Writer.Flush()
                End If
            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
            Try
                Client = New TcpClient(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), ip.Port))
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Sending: " & msg & " to: " & ip.Address.ToString)
                'Declare the Client as an IP Address. 
                'Must be in the Correct form. eg. 000.0.0.0
                Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
                Writer.Write(msg)
                Writer.Flush()
            Catch ex1 As Exception

            End Try
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Listener.Pending = True Then
            Message = ""
            Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()

            Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Client.GetStream())
            While Reader.Peek > -1
                Message = Message + Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString
            End While
            Parse(Message, Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Any suggestions, please, If it's duplicate, please just link to another post, I don't have even the words to ask this on google

Answer (score 0):

Can you break this down into 2 sections?   Client Send & Recieve code and server send & receive code?

First off no computer has the same IP. Your client IP machine can have the IP address of `192.168.1.125` and your server machine could have `192.168.1.56`.  2 machines connected to a network can never have a conflicting IP address.

I have successfully coded my own client/server application that works on the internet and the intranet (home network).  I can help you.

But please break your code down into 2 sections of Client Side & Server Side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).